# how to redirect a 403 forbidden page (assets folder) to custom error page in angular 12

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, web-config

When user browses base url followed by assets/ or data/ then user is getting 403 forbidden page. we are trying to show general error message for all types of status codes (400,403,5xx,401). We have created a custom error page component for redirection.

i have tried adding wild card routing and also i have tried the below lines in routing module, but it didn't work.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'assets/', component: ErrorHandlerComponent },
  { path: 'data/', component: ErrorHandlerComponent },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorHandlerComponent }
];
```

Comment: The wildcard routing only works for 404 errors. Other errors need to be handled by your code. I never did it, but a guard may help you in this case.

Comment: You can use an http interceptor and based on status code you can redirect to custom page